# Logic not working with List items in Applescript

Tags: applescript

This is a very strange problem I could not understand it, the code is very clear as you can see, I don't know if I am tired or could not see something... please tell me why I am getting False as a result, while it should be True, I have a list with one item and it is the exact one in the variable 
thanks

```
property forbidenFolders : {"/Volumes/USERS/"}
set ff to "/Volumes/USERS/" as text
my isForbidenFolder(ff)
on isForbidenFolder(SelectedFolder)
    repeat with i in forbidenFolders
        log "forbiden folders: " & i
        log "actual folder   : " & SelectedFolder
        if i = SelectedFolder then
            log "this folder is forbiden"
            return true
        end if
    end repeat
    log "NOT forbiden"
    return false
end isForbidenFolder
```

result here

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the reference trap.

The syntax `repeat with item in list` iterates thru the list with references e.g. `a reference to item 1 of list`, `a reference to item 2 of list` etc. rather than the item itself.

To be able to check for equality you have to dereference the item using `contents of`

```
if contents of i = SelectedFolder then
```

Comment: Thank you Man you alaways save me

Answer (score 0):

When i is set to the item of a list in a repeat loop, you are getting a reference to the item. You need to coerce it into a string for your comparison.

```
if (i as string) = SelectedFolder
```